# Why is my image speed not changing?

Tags: movement, game-maker

Following is my code for my platformer. However, in the `//Run with left shift//` section when I made the image speed change, the speed is still the same and doesn't change so is there any piece of code that is preventing this task?

```
///Get player's input
key_right = keyboard_check(vk_right);
key_left = -keyboard_check(vk_left);
key_jump = keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space);
key_jump_held = keyboard_check(vk_space);
key_shoot = keyboard_check(ord("D"));

//React to inputs
move = key_left + key_right;
hsp = move * movespeed;
if (vsp < 10) vsp += grav;

if (place_meeting(x, y+1, Obj_Floor))
{
 vsp = key_jump * -jumpspeed;
}

if (vsp < 0) && (!key_jump_held) vsp = max(vsp,0)

//Run with left shift
if (keyboard_check(vk_lshift)) 
{
 movespeed = 5;
 image_speed = 0.14; 
}

if (keyboard_check_released(vk_lshift))
{
 movespeed = 3;
 image_speed = 0.025;
}

//Shooting direction
if (keyboard_check(vk_right))
{
 mpfacing = 0;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_left))
{
 mpfacing = 180;
}

//Shooting
if (keyboard_check(ord("D"))) && (canshoot = true)
{
 instance_create(x+13, y-0.5, Obj_MP_Laser);
 canshoot = false;
 alarm[1] = 30;
}


//Horizontal Collision
if (place_meeting(x+hsp, y, Obj_Floor))
{
 while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp), y, Obj_Floor))
 {
  x += sign(hsp);
 }
 hsp = 0;
}
x += hsp;

//Vertical Collision
if (place_meeting(x, y+vsp, Obj_Floor))
{
 while(!place_meeting(x, y+sign(vsp), Obj_Floor))
 {
  y += sign(vsp);
 }
 vsp = 0;
}
y += vsp;

//Animate
if (move != 0) 
{
 image_xscale = move;
}

if (place_meeting(x, y+1, Obj_Floor))
{

 if (move != 0) 
 { 
  sprite_index = CalvinWalking;
  image_speed = 0.05;
 } 

 else 
 {
  sprite_index = CalvinStanding;
  image_speed = 0.025;
 }
}

else
{
 if (vsp < 0) sprite_index = CalvinJumping
 else sprite_index = CalvinJumping
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code seems to be here:

```
 if (move != 0) 
 { 
      sprite_index = CalvinWalking;
      image_speed = 0.05;
 } 

 else 
 {
      sprite_index = CalvinStanding;
      image_speed = 0.025;
 }
```

Right now you're saying this:

```
if player is pressing left or right:
    set sprite_index = CalvinWalking
    set image_speed = 0.05
otherwise if player is not pressing left or right:
    set sprite_index = CalvinStanding
    set image_speed = 0.025
```

Every frame you're checking whether or not the player is pressing the <kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd> key, and if they aren't to adjust the speed. Because you do this after you check if the player is pressing the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, the players speed never increases.

A few things to note:

1. I'm fairly certain that GM compiles code much like C++, in that it compiles line by line (don't quote me on this)
2. When organising code, you should generally try to isolate things; for example, you're managing collision detection, player input, shooting **and** animations, you should try to isolate these things into separate scripts, this way you can easily turn things on and off and will determine what the issue is.